# Getting two log messages that seems to stall the website running Vaadin 8 with tomcat behind apache using mod_jk

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, vaadin, mod-jk

I keep getting lots of these warnings in my logs:

```
WARN  o.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster - Duplicate resource fda35646-a562-4366-933a-ba93a01297ea. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one
```

and:

```
WARN  c.v.server.ConnectorResourceHandler - Ignoring connector request for no-existent connector 7866 in root 1
WARN  c.v.server.ConnectorResourceHandler - Ignoring connector request for no-existent connector 8582 in root 4
```

As well sometimes the whole website seems to just kind of lock up, where no actions are possible. I'm still trying to connect the log errors with these lockups but either way as soon as I do a refresh of the page everything is back to normal. It's intermittent but seems to happen several times a day in my testing.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with mod_jk or something related because it only happens in the environment setup with apache in front of tomcat connected with mod_jk. Just tomcat by itself has none of these log warnings.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.